# WebDAV + MS Office - request login/password every time on saving new documents

Tags: windows, ms-office, webdav, nextcloud

When open MS document from mapped WebDAV disk, MS Office ask request login/password every time on saving new documents.

I know this is a Windows / Office Issue, but I think there needs to be a Registry Setting to make it just work as it works with any other tool like notepad etc.

Nextcloud version 27.1.1
PHP version 8.1.22
mysql version: 8.0.34
Apache

Steps to replicate it:

Install
Try to use mapped WebDAV disk with MS Office